# PL/SQL code to create a oracle scheduler job with job_owner and job_creator as a specified schema

Tags: bash, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a PL/SQL code to create ab Oracle scheduler job with `job_owner` and `job_creator` as a specified schema as I do not want to create the scheduler job with `job_creator` and `job_owner` as *SYS*. I have granted "connect" through to a proxy user to connect to the desired schema under which the scheduler job needs to be created. I need help with this code. Is the logic I'm using to satisfy my requirements correct? Or this can implemented in another, better way? Although I'm using this logic, I'm landing in error while creating the scheduler job. There must me some syntax error while creating the job. Could experts please help?

```
# Run the PL/SQL block
set -vx

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
{

        echo "Invalid Parameter passed to the script"
        exit 1;
}
fi

#SOURCE ENV FILE

. ${1}
. ${v_env}   # Source Oracle Env File

sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << SQLEND
DECLARE
   l_schema_owner      VARCHAR2 (240);
   l_specific_id         NUMBER := 1;
   l_repeat_interval   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   l_job_action        VARCHAR2 (2000);
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR i
      IN (SELECT owner,start_date, repeat_interval, next_run_date
            FROM all_scheduler_jobs
           WHERE job_name = 'XYZ' || l_specific_id
                 AND UPPER(owner) like UPPER('ABC'))
   LOOP
      IF INSTR (i.repeat_interval, 'SECOND') != 0
         OR (INSTR (i.repeat_interval, 'MINUTE') != 0
             AND SUBSTR (i.repeat_interval,
                         INSTR (i.repeat_interval,
                                '=',
                                1,
                                2)
                         + 1) < 2)
      THEN
         l_schema_owner:=i.owner;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA='||i.owner;
         sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job (
            'XYZ' || l_client_id,
            TRUE);


         l_job_action :=
            'DECLARE
                                            l_errbuf  VARCHAR2(500); l_retcode   NUMBER;
                                           BEGIN
                                                MNOP_JOB_SCHEDULER_PKG.EXECUTE_JOB (l_errbuf, l_retcode,'
            || l_specific_id
            || ',''MINUTELY'','
            || TO_CHAR (2)
            || ');
                                            COMMIT;
                                           END;';



         l_repeat_interval := 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=2';
         l_schema_owner:=i.owner;
         sql_stmt := 'CONNECT PROXY[l_schema_owner]/passwd';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
         DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
            job_name          => l_schema_owner || '.' || 'XYZ' || l_specific_id,
            job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action        => l_job_action,
            start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
            repeat_interval   => l_repeat_interval,
            end_date          => NULL,
            enabled           => TRUE,
            comments          => 'testing  Manager Setup FOR Client ID-'
                                || l_client_id);

         COMMIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
SQLEND
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: "Im landing in error while creating the scheduler job, there must me some syntax error" - why not tell us the error then? But you can't `connect` in the middle of a block like that, as it would end this session and start a new one; and `connect` is a client command, not SQL you can run dynamically anyway - so that will get ORA-00900. Why are you doing that at all when you're already prefixing the job name with the schema anyway? If there are other errors you'll need to debug the statements you are running.

Comment: @AlexPoole adding my error details. Although Im creating the job with schema prefix the job_owner is the mentioned schema but I want the job creator to be the same schema thats why Im trying to login to schema in middle of block. As this is not an viable could you suggest an alternate method to do this? 
thanks
`SQLEND
+ sqlplus -s '/ as sysdba'
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 47
ORA-06512: at line 47`

Answer (score 2):

The `CONNECT` command is for SQL*Plus and cannot run natively in SQL. That's why this code is failing:

```
         sql_stmt := 'CONNECT PROXY[l_schema_owner]/passwd';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt ;
```

Unfortunately, this means the shell script needs to be changed to have multiple transitions between bash, SQL*Plus, and SQL.

An alternative approach would be to use the powerful and undocumented package [DBMS_SYS_SQL](https://www.pythian.com/blog/using-dbms_sys_sql-to-execute-statements-as-another-user). That package allows SYS to run commands as a specific user. Keep in mind that undocumented code could change or disappear in a future release, so be careful using that feature.